# Junit: injecting a dependency

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I was facing an issue regarding injecting dependencies in a class.

Class A had a dependency, B, which is annotated with @Autowired. B class is itself annotated with @Service

In unit test for A, situation was as:

```
@InjectMocks
private A a = new A();

@Mock B b
```

This worked fine. b in unit test is mocked, and in class A dependency B gets injected correctly.

Then I made a change and now A has another dependency, C. C is also a service and its is also automwired in A, just like B.

In unit test I now do:

```
@InjectMocks
private A a = new A();

@Mock 
B b;

@Mock 
C c;
```

But it doesn't work. In unit test code, c is mocked, but in A dependency  C is not injected and its null.

On google search, I came across [this](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/) article. It gives solution but I am not able to understand why dependency C doesn't get injected, while B gets injected.

Comment: Can you try removing the `= new A()` on the `a` field?

Comment: Also, add `@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}` in case it is not added already

Comment: It gives me error
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'a'! Cause: the type 'A' is an interface.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.

Comment: Is `A` an interface or a class?

Comment: interface...so it can't be instantiated.

Comment: in sample code, A is concrete implementation. Sorry for that confusion.

Comment: So can you confirm if in your test, you have `A` a class or an interface?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191978/discussion-between-mandroid-and-madhu-bhat).